# Bug? Click (and/or focus) in FFX and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Basically go here: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ3vk/52/

HTML

```
<form name="form1">     <input type="radio" name=button1>Box 1    <br>         <input type="radio" name=button1>Box 2    <br><br>
```

Javascript

```
$('input').focus(function(){console.log("a");});
```

In chrome first and you will notice that if you click on the radio you'll get a conole.log message. This makes sense because if I click on something it not only counts as a click but also as being "in focus".

In Firefox, this is not the case. If you hit tab, it counts, and you get the log message but if you select the radio you don't.

Which one is right?

Comment: Using `FF 38.0.5` this is not the case. I am getting a console log on click.

Comment: What version of `Firefox` are you using?

Comment: Looks like this was the answer I was looking for: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756028

Comment: I am using FFX 38.0.5

Comment: Here is a gif of what I am seeing: http://g.recordit.co/Cv77kYy8na.gif

Comment: Would be better also by closing the form tag properly as you are missing </form>